# how could i make this look less vomit enducing? lines

Tags: gimp

maybe if i was radiating out some grey from the letters? to give them more shape, just like light grey emitating from the edges of the letters and dropping away to nothing within a few pixels, would that do the trick?

maybe outline it? but i fear that will detract from the general coolness of it. :/

does anyone know a good way to do that using gimp?

maybe some people have some other ideas. [image]

Comment: The unevenness of the lines is jarring. Why is the center bar of the E not equal to the H? It may also look better if the body of the letters has more 'meat' -- I assume this is a regular font, so try a bold variant.

Comment: ah cool. good suggestion. i was also thinking about, maybe if I fatted up the horizontal lines too. i think whats going on is your brain tries to continue the lines across but when they suddendly break its like a kind of optical illusion. do you know of a place where i can set exactly the number of pixels of my font? i guess it should all be even you know. i need to calculate it mathematically.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. On the SE Network questions should be a bit more specific than, "how can I make this less vomit inducing?" I mean you could type the letter with normal font on a white background, but I highly doubt that's the answer your looking for. It merely illustrates that your Question is not specific at all.

Comment: Getting away from human preception ilusions without scrapping the design is a bit challenging.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be the name of this particular illusion? It is not the "cafe wall" or a "grid illusion", although similar to those. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optical_illusions

Comment: gotta love wikipedia lists, i think maybe this one `Motion aftereffect`

Comment: A bit of antialiasing could help...

Comment: what do you mean by that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a drop shadow improved the overal "feeling" for me - but it might break the exact effect you intend, as it makes the whole thing easy to spot in an automatic way (without one having to stare at the picture until find counciously what the letters are).

I also remade the concept by creating the stripes with the grid filter (`filters->render->pattern->grid`and set "line width" to 0 - in this case I did use "height" = 12 and line-height=6), using a text layer as selection (Select by color is your friend), and copy-pasting the lines to a layer I could move in an independent way.

(After setting things in place, `filters->Light and Shadow->Drop Shadow` - one with less opacity than what is shown here may look better)

[image: remade image]

Extra hint: write the text with a Sans Serif, Bold font (everytime you want to add image effects to the letters themselves)

Comment: you did this with gimp?

Comment: it's sort of vomit enducing tho, maybe if I fatted up the horizontal lines?

Comment: Yes. The steps to reproduce are listed above(if they are not detailed enough for you to reproduce, I could expand on that)

Comment: Once you get to this, the letters are in a separate layer, and it is easy to experiment with their opacity/color -

Comment: could you explain once again how you made the horizontal lines? I got the grid filter part, but then what?

Comment: Pick the grid filter, uncouple (toggle the chain icon) for line width/height, and set the line width to 0. Therefore, only lines with "height" (i.e. horizontal lines) will be drawn